# How to add comma or any punctuation as element of list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, tuples

I have this string :

```
("abs, aaaa aaa")
```

I want to return this :

```
("abs",",","aaaa","aaa")
```

I tried this :

```
([i for item in lst for i in item.split()])
```

But it returns this :

```
("abs","aaaa","aaa")
```

Comment: since there is no space `' '` before `,` `abs,` is considered as single word.

Comment: so it means it can't be added?

Comment: You need to manually handle this kind of case to achieve desired result. Can you give one more example of input output? `"abs ,,, aaa"`. what would be output of this?

Comment: Thierry's `re` approach is the way to go. but if you want a raw list-comp solution:
`[word or ',' for comma_word in "abs, aaaa aaa".split() for word in comma_word.split(',')]`

Comment: @Poojan the output would be like this ["abs", "," , "," , "," , "aaa"]

Answer (score 4):

You could do that with a regex:

```
import re

data = "abs, aaaa    aaa"

out = re.findall(r'\w+|\S', data)

print(out)
# ['abs', ',', 'aaaa', 'aaa']
```

We look for either words (`\w+`) or any non-space character (`\S`)

Comment: is it possible to add comma and space

Answer (score 2):

My solution is simple: replace all commas with " , " and then split:

```
lst = "abc, aaaa aaa"
lst.replace(",", " , ").split()  # ==> ['abs', ',', 'aaaa', 'aaa']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

tokenizer = TweetTokenizer()
tokenizer.tokenize("abs, aaaa aaa")

#op
['abs', ',', 'aaaa', 'aaa']
```